# Organizing Data by comparing matching lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of varying sizes I'm running through the same function, I'm matching them against a shorter list, to find similar IDs.  But I'm having issues sorting the data.  Ultimately I want to pair data so that the shorter list, and long list's entries will pair correctly and I can run scripts on the resulting pairs.

```
matchList = [[235876728, 235876768], [235876728, 235876688]]

longList = [[235876728, 240000000, 235876768, 250000000], [260000000, 270000000, 235876768, 235876768],[235876728, 235876688, 280000000, 290000000],[300000000,235876728, 310000000, 235876688]]

shortList = [[235876728, 235876768, 320000000, 330000000],[340000000, 235876728,  235876768, 350000000]]
```

desiredList would consist of an entry for each entry of matchList, and in each entry, you'd have the matched entries from the long list, against an entry for the shortList

```
desiredList = [(([23235876728, 235876768],[235876728, 235876768]),([235876728, 235876768])),(([235876728, 235876688],[235876728, 235876688]),([235876728, 235876688]))]
```

OR essentially

```
desiredList = [(([longListEntry],[LongListEntry]),([shortListEntry])),(([longListEntry], [longListEntry]), ([shortListEntry]))
```

Each list (match, long and short) will vary in size so it has to be dynamic, so if matchList has 8 entries, the desiredList will 8 entries, each entry consisting of a variable size of matched pairs.

Comment: Sorry - your explanation and examples ar enot enoguh for anyone figureing out what you actually want. If you have an ID you want to group elements by, just use it as a key for a dicionary. Then, export data from that dictionary to wherever you will consume it as lists, if needed.